# How to convert byte3 to int with Python

Tags: python, binary, byte, decode

I haven't experienced a binary file analysis so far.
I am trying to decode the binary file with python.
How would I convert the following bytes object that has a length of 3 to integer or string with Python?

e.g.) b'x05/x18/x27' => ????

Comment: does that solve your problem ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Comment: I'm not sure what you think "byte3" means. Did you mean, a `bytes` object that has a *length* of 3? In particular, I guess your example is supposed to be `b'\x05\x18\x27'`? Okay, then, what is the *rule that tells you* what the integer result, or string result, should be? What do you think the output should be for that specific input, and what is the reasoning that gets you there?

Comment: When you say that you want to "decode" a "binary file", exactly what kind of file? Is it used for a particular purpose? If so, does it have a particular **file format** that is documented somewhere? If so, did you **read** the documentation?

Comment: I am a beginner. I could not tell it well. You are right. The bytes object has a length of 3. b'\x05\x18\x27'. I thought it should be 4-digit number like a '1000' when I applied b'\x05\x18\x27b'.decode('utf-8'). However, It was corrupted. The rule of binary file which I want to decode has not been published yet. So it has no document. But somehow I would have like to decode it by myself.

Comment: Maybe `int.from_bytes(b'\x05\x18\x27','big')`? Or even `int.from_bytes( b'\x05\x18\x27b', 'big')` ?